# Ordenar un ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo un ArrayList que quiero ordenar, utilicé el método sort() pero me devuelve un void, cómo hago para pasarlo a Double?

```html
public static Double calculateMediana(){
        mediana =  Collections.sort(li);
        return mediana;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

el collections.sort() no se asigna a una variable, tu pones Collection.sort(li); y te ordena los valores dentro del arraylist li. No es posible añadir un conjunto de valores a una sola variable. Aun asi no se de donde sacas el arraylist li ya que el metodo no recibe ningun valor.